# How to solve access restriction error in IIS

Tags: asp.net, windows, server, iis-7

When I setup the website in IIS 7, iam not able to acces the website and I get access restriction which states that you are not authorised for access to the requested page.

I tried all possibilities but not luck. Please help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Status code is very critical for further discussion, so you need to edit your question to include such, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/iis/http-status-code Ideally, the whole screen shot is needed.

Comment: According to your description, I couldn’t understand your requirement clearly. please post more details information about your requirement.